# How to enable Chinese on Debian lenny?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny

I have already

1. installed Chinese fonts

   ```
   $ sudo apt-cache search chinese
   $ sudo apt-get install ttf-arphic-bkai00mp ttf-arphic-bsmi00lp ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ...
   ```
2. added locales

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales,
   ```

and chose the following

- en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
- zh_CN GB2312
- zh_CN.GBK GBK
- zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8
- zh_TW BIG5
- zh_TW.UTF-8 UTF-8

However when I try to create a file with Chinese characters in file name by `touch <some chinese characters ...>.txt`, it fails and substituted Chinese characters with `---------` at terminal.

How to fix this?

### [Edit, Aug. 15, 2011, 21:42]

After rebooting, everything is working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell your terminal to use the Chinese locale; I'm no multilingual expert, but if you've got a UTF-8 compatibile terminal, I would expect that adding the following to your `.bashrc` and logging out/in:

```
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

or

```
export LANG=zh_TW.UTF-8
```

(depending on your particular preference) should do the trick.